# Create Screenshot of all elementos of View instead capture original View on swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

**EDIT:** Edit my code with @jnpdx suggestions and I get this image saved result:
[image: resultAfterModifications]

Basically, when I touch any button on the components, this touch (changes color), it affects all the buttons on all the reused components, how can I manage the states independently? That is, if the central button in figure 18 changes it to blue, it does not affect the other components
This is my code modified:

```
import SwiftUI

struct OdontogramView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.displayScale) var displayScale
    
    @State private var sheetPresented : Bool = false
    @State private var showSavingDataAlert = false
    
    @State private var odontogramShapeColorProperties = OdontogramColorsProperties()
    @State private var odontogramCircularColorProperties = OdontogramColorsProperties()
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = AddRecordViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView([.vertical,.horizontal], showsIndicators: true) {
                odontogramElements()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(NSLocalizedString("odontogramTitle", comment: "title")), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                // MARK: - Saving image
                self.sheetPresented.toggle()
            }) {
                Text(NSLocalizedString("addrecords_view_buttonTitleLeft", comment: ""))
                    .bold()
            })
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                print(("Help"))
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            }))
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                dismiss()
            }) {
                Text(NSLocalizedString("addrecords_view_buttonTitleRight", comment: ""))
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            })
            
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetPresented, content: {
                if let data = render() {
                    CaptureScrollViewViewController(activityItems: [data])
                }
                
            })
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
    
    private func getIntervalNumbers(starts: Int, end: Int, ascend: Bool) -> [String] {
        var result: [String] = []
        if ascend {
            for num in starts...end {
                result.append(String(num))
            }
        } else {
            for num in (end...starts).reversed() {
                result.append(String(num))
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

extension OdontogramView {
    private func odontogramElements() -> some View {
        VStack {
            // MARK: - First Section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                // Left section | Shape
                ForEach(getIntervalNumbers(starts: 18, end: 11, ascend: false), id: \.self) { number in
                    OdontogramSquareComponenteView(buttonState: $odontogramShapeColorProperties, topNumber: number, bottomNumber: nil)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                }
                Divider()
                    .frame(width: 5)
                    .overlay(.black)
                // Right | Shape
                ForEach(getIntervalNumbers(starts: 21, end: 28, ascend: true), id: \.self) { number in
                    OdontogramSquareComponenteView(buttonState: $odontogramShapeColorProperties, topNumber: number, bottomNumber: nil)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                }
            }
            // MARK: - Second section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                // Left | Circle
                ForEach(getIntervalNumbers(starts: 55, end: 51, ascend: false), id: \.self) { number in
                    OdontogramCircleComponentView(buttonState: $odontogramCircularColorProperties, topNumber: number, bottomNumber: nil)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                }
                Divider()
                    .frame(width: 5)
                    .overlay(.black)
                // Right - Circle
                ForEach(getIntervalNumbers(starts: 61, end: 65, ascend: true), id: \.self) { number in
                    OdontogramCircleComponentView(buttonState: $odontogramCircularColorProperties, topNumber: number, bottomNumber: nil)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                }
            }
            Divider()
                .frame(height: 5)
                .overlay(.black)
            // MARK: - Third section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                // Left | Shape
                ForEach(getIntervalNumbers(starts: 85, end: 81, ascend: false), id: \.self) { number in
                    OdontogramCircleComponentView(buttonState: $odontogramCircularColorProperties, topNumber: nil, bottomNumber: number)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                }
                Divider()
                    .frame(width: 5)
                    .overlay(.black)
                // Right | Shape
                ForEach(getIntervalNumbers(starts: 71, end: 75, ascend: true), id: \.self) { number in
                    OdontogramCircleComponentView(buttonState: $odontogramCircularColorProperties, topNumber: nil, bottomNumber: number)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                }
            }
            // MARK: - Fourth section
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                // Left | Circle
                ForEach(getIntervalNumbers(starts: 48, end: 41, ascend: false), id: \.self) { number in
                    OdontogramSquareComponenteView(buttonState: $odontogramShapeColorProperties, topNumber: nil, bottomNumber: number)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                }
                Divider()
                    .frame(width: 5)
                    .overlay(.black)
                // Right | Circle
                ForEach(getIntervalNumbers(starts: 31, end: 38, ascend: true), id: \.self) { number in
                    OdontogramSquareComponenteView(buttonState: $odontogramShapeColorProperties, topNumber: nil, bottomNumber: number)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.all, 20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension OdontogramView {
    @MainActor
    private func render() -> UIImage? {
        let odontogramElements = odontogramElements()
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: odontogramElements)
        renderer.scale = displayScale
        return renderer.uiImage
    }
}
```

And the code of the component is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct OdontogramColorsProperties: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var top: Color = .clear
    var left: Color = .clear
    var right: Color = .clear
    var bottom: Color = .clear
    var center: Color = .clear
    var clickCount: Int = 0
    var isTopLineVisible: Bool = false
    var isBottomLineVisible: Bool = false
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}

struct OdontogramSquareComponenteView: View {
    
    @Binding var buttonState: OdontogramColorsProperties
    
    var topNumber: String?
    var bottomNumber: String?
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            // MARK: - Number label top
            if buttonState.isTopLineVisible {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 10, alignment: .center)
            }
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    buttonState.isTopLineVisible.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text(topNumber ?? "")
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            buttonState.isTopLineVisible.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
            ZStack {
                if colorScheme == .dark {
                    Image("ShapeOdontogramDark")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                } else {
                    Image("ShapeOdontogram")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                }
                
                // MARK: - Top button
                Button(action: {
                    switch buttonState.top {
                    case .clear:
                        buttonState.top = .blue
                    case .blue:
                        buttonState.top = .red
                    case .red:
                        buttonState.top = .clear
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(buttonState.top)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(100, corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight])
                }
                .offset(x: 0, y: -83)
                
                // MARK: - Left button
                Button(action: {
                    switch buttonState.left {
                    case .clear:
                        buttonState.left = .blue
                    case .blue:
                        buttonState.left = .red
                    case .red:
                        buttonState.left = .clear
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(buttonState.left)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(100, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
                }
                .offset(x: -83, y: 0)
                
                // MARK: - Right button
                Button(action: {
                    switch buttonState.right {
                    case .clear:
                        buttonState.right = .blue
                    case .blue:
                        buttonState.right = .red
                    case .red:
                        buttonState.right = .clear
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(buttonState.right)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(100, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
                }
                .offset(x: 83, y: 0)
                
                // MARK: - Bottom button
                Button(action: {
                    switch buttonState.bottom {
                    case .clear:
                        buttonState.bottom = .blue
                    case .blue:
                        buttonState.bottom = .red
                    case .red:
                        buttonState.bottom = .clear
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(buttonState.bottom)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(100, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
                }
                .offset(x: 0, y: 83)
                
                // MARK: Center button
                Button(action: {
                    buttonState.clickCount += 1
                    
                    switch buttonState.clickCount {
                    case 1:
                        buttonState.center = .blue
                    case 2:
                        buttonState.center = .red
                    case 3...5:
                        buttonState.center = .clear
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(buttonState.center)
                            .frame(width: 130, height: 130, alignment: .center)
                        if buttonState.clickCount >= 4 {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        } else if buttonState.clickCount >= 3 {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // MARK: - Number label bottom
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    buttonState.isBottomLineVisible.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text(bottomNumber ?? "")
                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            buttonState.isBottomLineVisible.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
            
            if buttonState.isBottomLineVisible {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 10, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
        .padding(.all, 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Extrapolate the contents into a non-stateful component that doesn't have the `@State` properties and just gets data passed in. Then, pass that same data into the one you create the image from.

Comment: I try to do that but it is not efficient because I have too many buttons in many components, I already edited my question putting an example of one of the components that I reuse @jnpdx

Comment: Your component could be _much_ simpler with _one_ `@State` that has a struct with all of those properties.

Comment: I edit the question @jnpdx and got a result where one interaction affects all components, any idea how to handle everything separately?

Comment: Yes — you can’t just pass the same state to each component. One solution would be to create an array and pass each component one element of the array.